# Using async callback to pass jsondata between functions

Tags: javascript

I have function that sends xmlreq to get json and in another function i use the json data to do some stuff with it. I have searched and come across "callbacks" but the console log says its not "defined" in my secound function where i do stuff with the json.

Any suggestions? Or is there another way of doing this with js?

Javascript:

```
function get_xml(url,callback) {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function myfunction() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var jsonData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            callback(jsonData);
            return callback;
        }
        else if (xhr.status == 400) {
            alert('There was an error 400');
        }
        else {
            alert('Var vänlig och försök igen! Tack för din tålamod!');
             }


    }

};

xhr.open("GET", url, true);

xhr.send();

}

function countries() {
    console.log(jsonData);
}

document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", () => {
    var url = "something";
    get_xml(url,countries);
});
```

Comment: I want to use xml_get func few times later in other events

Comment: The modern way is to use `fetch`... not `XMLHttpRequest` directly. Then use promises.

Comment: @trincot yes ive come across that and that method is really cool, but im working on a school project and we have only been learing how to use xml, and with the timeframe  i have i cant learn new "method", thanks for suggestion tho ill look at it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting the jsonData in you `countries` function.

```js
function countries(jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

Comment: LOL, thanks for your answer man! It works! i will accept in 10 minutes since the site doesnt let me to accept it now.

Answer (score 0):

Need to accept the parameter in callback function

```
function countries(jsonData) {
    console.log(jsonData);
}
```

return statement called as an empty function, need to pass the JSON data

~~return callback~~

use

```
return
```

or

```
return callback(jsonData);
```